# Move bundle options via XML - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

I've tried absolutely everything I can think of to move the bundle options but for some reason they won't move.

When you click the customize and add to cart button it's those options that I want to move to below the button. See below....

[image]

In my `catalog_product_view.xml` I've tried the below and many other combinations:

`<move element="product.info" destination="product.info.main" before="-" />`

`<move element="product.info.form.content" destination="product.info.main" before="-" />`

`<move element="product.add.form" destination="product.info.main" before="-" />`

`<move element="bundle.options.container" destination="product.info.main" before="-" />`

As a different approach, I tried moving the product description below the bundle options instead:

`<move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info" />`

`<move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.form.content" />`

`<move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" after="product.add.form" />`

`<move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" after="bundle.options.container" />`

Nothing is working :(

Can someone help me with this please? Many thanks in advance.

## Requested catalog_product_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

<body>

   <!-- Remove compare products -->
  <referenceBlock name="view.addto.compare" remove="true" />

  <!-- Remove social share links -->
  <referenceBlock name="product.info.social" remove="true" />

  <!-- Move product short description after price  -->
  <move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" after="-" />

  <!-- Move related products before short description -->
  <move element="catalog.product.related" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.overview" />


  <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
      <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="welpixel.quickview.beforebodyend" template="Magento_Catalog::beforebodyend.phtml" />
  </referenceContainer>

  <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" name="product.info.options.default" as="default" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>
 </body>
```

Comment: can u please share your catalog_product_view.xml file code?

Comment: Sure, I've added it to my question above :)

Comment: Code posted. check and let me know it's working for you or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit late returning here but I found the solution...

It's within the Magento Bundle module so in your theme have the following structure

```
Magento_Bundle
   layout
       catalog_view_type_bundle.xml
```

And within the XML add:

`<move element="bundle.options.container" destination="product.info.main" before="catalog.product.related" />`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add below line in `catalog_product_view.xml` file

```
<move element="bundle.options.container" destination="product.info.main" after="customize.button"/>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: That doesn't work I'm afraid. It's one of the things I listed in my question that I've already tried :(

Comment: it's working for me. i have checked and uploaded code here